# angular auth0 json web token strategy for the reload

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I've followed this very good tutorial
https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Client side I'm using https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt
storing the token in session storage.

What type of strategy do you use if you
want the user to be logged at the next 
visit the site ?

By now I've thought to store the token
in local storage and than check if token is expired
if not using to get ie the username.
Of course if the token is expired do login.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Do you mean page refresh (title suggest that) or next visit  - user closed the browser (that's what you seem to be asking)?

Comment: @M.M next visit - user closed the browser